# Not getting Required output of Main Diagonal of matrix JAVA

Tags: java, for-loop, matrix

This program is suppose to: 
"Ask the user for a number n.  Create a nxn integer matrix.  Fill the matrix with random numbers between 0 and 9 using the seed of 5 (remember, when we seed a random number generator we get predictable "random" numbers).

For full credit, calculate the sum of the diagonal starting in the upper left corner of the matrix (index [0][0]).  Display that sum to the screen."

The professor answer:
"For a 100 x 100 matrix, the main diagonal should have a sum of 503 and the other diagonal should have a sum of 444."

My program answer: 700 for main diagonal. So I'm guessing it's something wrong with my MakeandFillMatrix method.

```
import java.util.*;
/*

*/
public class TesterProject
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        int n = getMatrixSize();
        int[][] m = makeAndFillMatrix(n);
        printMatrix(m);

        int sumD1 = calculateMainDiagonal(m);
        System.out.println("The sum of the main diagonal is " + sumD1);
    }
    public static int getMatrixSize()
    {
        Scanner S = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("give me a int to create the matrix");
        while(!S.hasNextInt())
        {
            System.out.println("I need an integer!");
            S.next();
        }
        int n = S.nextInt();
        return n;
    }
    public static int [][] makeAndFillMatrix(int n)
    {
        Random generator = new Random(5);
        int [][] r = new int[n][n];
        int rand = generator.nextInt(10);

        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                r[i][j] = rand;
                //rand++;
            }
        }
        return r;
        /*
        for(int i = 0; i < r.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < r[i].length; j++)
            {
                r[i][j]= rand;
            }
        }
        return r;
        */
    }
    public static void printMatrix(int [][] matrix)
    {
        for(int r = 0; r < matrix.length; r++)
        {
            for(int c = 0; c < matrix[r].length; c++)
            {
                System.out.print(matrix[r][c] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    public static int calculateMainDiagonal(int [][] m)
    {
        int total = 0;
        for (int r = 0; r < m.length; r++)
        {
                total += m[r][r];
        }
        return total;
    }
}
```

Comment: step through your program with a debugger, its a skill you need to learn early

Comment: The program works and everything, It just doesn't give the require output.

Comment: so that means it doesnt work. My original comment still stands. There should be absolutely no guesswork required. Just learn how to use a debugger that comes integrated with any modern IDE

Comment: You are using the same "random" number for every element of the matrix, which not really what is being requested. Because I am a wizard, I can deduce that the number is 7.

Comment: If your program controlled an x-ray machine and caused a lethal amount of radiation to be emitted if the operator pressed SHIFT+SPACE at the same time, would you say your program worked and everything but it just didn't give the required output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are only generating the random number once.  You will see that your matrix is composed of only 7, no matter what.  When you write `r[i][j] = rand`, you really should be setting that element to be a new random number.  Remove the line `rand = generator.nextInt(10)` and change the previously mentioned line to be `r[i][j] = generator.nextInt(10)`.

Comment: Wow, I would have never thought of that. Thank you.